# как превратить enum HKCategoryValueSeverity (HealthKit) в CaseIterable enum?

Tags: swift, swiftui

как превратить enum HKCategoryValueSeverity (HealthKit) в CaseIterable enum?

для дальнейшего перебора значений в Picker поле.

Если сделать так:

```
extension HKCategoryValueSeverity: CaseIterable {
```

то xCode напишет:

> Extension outside of file declaring enum 'HKCategoryValueSeverity'
> prevents automatic synthesis of 'allCases' for protocol 'CaseIterable'

и предложит исправить

```
public static var allCases: [HKCategoryValueSeverity]
```

естественно если заполнить вот так в ручную

```
public static var allCases: [HKCategoryValueSeverity] {
 return [.unspecified, .notPresent, mild, .moderate, .severe]   
}
```

то все получается. Но. ВОПРОС:

**а как заполнить allCases автоматически из кейсов энума HKCategoryValueSeverity?**

для последующего

```
ForEach(HKCategoryValueSeverity.allCases) { category in

// code

}
```

что-то типа

```
return self.allCases.map({ $0 })
```

но на это xcode ругается

> Function call causes an infinite recursion